# Downloading files in folder using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I am downloading files in a folder using selenium.I can see all my files downloaded in that folder but files with extension .docx is not downloaded to that folder.These files are downloading in downloads folder in my system.

Snippet of my code i am using.

```
    if (driverpath.endsWith(".exe")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverpath);
    } else {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverpath + "chromedriver.exe");
    }
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Desktop" + File.separator
            + "Redesign_Downloaded_Files").mkdir();
    HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
    String downloadFilepath = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Desktop" + File.separator
            + "Redesign_Downloaded_Files";
    chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
    options.addExtensions(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "extension_1_5_294.crx"));
    options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
    DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    return new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

Is there any other way i can set that extensions files should be downloaded to that folder?

Comment: Can you try updating the chromedriver, browser and stand alone and check

Answer (score 0):

for your case, you are welcome to try my recent open-source [library](https://github.com/AutomatedOwl/selenium-download-kpi):
It would allow you to define your download folder both globally and locally in one code line, as well as other download related features.

To easily set up you download folder in your test using the library:

```
private SeleniumDownloadKPI seleniumDownloadKPI;

@BeforeEach
void setUpTest() {

    // New instance of SeleniumDownloadKPI with given download folder.
    seleniumDownloadKPI =
         new SeleniumDownloadKPI("/tmp/downloads");
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions =
            seleniumDownloadKPI.generateDownloadFolderCapability();
    driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```